# Check-In File Solidworks API using Enterprise PDM (PDMworks) C#

Tags: c#, winforms, solidworks

I Want to be able to check in a drawing using PDMworks, but can't figure it out for the life of me I will post what the website had below. All I want to do is check the drawing in and change its final state. If anyone has experience with this program I would really appreciate it. I am getting Error Expected ; or = (cannot specify constructor arguments in declaration) @ CheckIn(

```
using PDMWorks.Interop.pdmworks;//PDM Reference 

public interface IPDMWConnection { } 
public interface IPDMWDocuments { } 
public interface IPDMWDocument { } 

private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Check Drawing Into PDM Change State "Roll to Standard" 
{ 
    var filename = textBox1.Text + ".slddrw"; 
    var project = "MLD028D"; 
    var number = "1"; 
    var description = "Configured Actuator Drawing"; 
    var note = "Configured by Actuator Generator"; 
    var revision = "--"; 
    var lifecycle = "Configured"; 
    bool retainOwnership = false; 
    object references = textBox1.Text + "sldasm"; 

    //CheckIn Drawing to PDM 
    PDMWDocument CheckIn( 
    filename, //filename- Name of the closed document to check in 
    project, //project- Name of the project to which the document belongs 
    number, //Number Document number 
    description, //Description Document description 
    note, //note Document notes 
    //PDMWRevisionOptionType i_revOption, //i_revOption - Revision option as defined in PDMWRevisionOptionType (see Remarks) 
    revision, //Revision - Document revision 
    lifecycle, //lifecycle - Document lifecycle status 
    retainOwnership, //RetainOwnership - (bool false)True to retain ownership of the document in the vault, false to not 
    references //References - Array of the full paths and filenames of any referenced documents to check in (see Remarks) 
    ); 
    MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text + " Drawing and Assembly Checked-In"); 
}
```

Comment: This is a link to the website http://help.solidworks.com/2011/English/api/pdmworksapi/PDMWorks.Interop.pdmworks~PDMWorks.Interop.pdmworks.IPDMWConnection~CheckIn.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally received an answer from solidworks here is how to check in a drawing and change state of your drawing.

```
using EdmLib; //Enterprise PDM Reference

      private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Check Drawing Into PDM Change State "Roll to Standard"
    {
        //Create a file vault interface and log in to a vault. 
        EdmVault5 vault = default(EdmVault5);
        vault = new EdmVault5();
        vault.LoginAuto("Engineering", 0);

        //Get the vault's root folder interface. 
        IEdmFile5 file = default(IEdmFile5);
        IEdmFile5 file2 = default(IEdmFile5);
        IEdmFolder5 folder = default(IEdmFolder5);
        folder = vault.RootFolder;

        //Check In Assembly
        file2 = vault.GetFileFromPath("file location", out folder);
        file2.UnlockFile(0, "Checked In By Configurator", 0, null);

        //Check In Drawing and Change State to "Roll to Standard"
        file = vault.GetFileFromPath("file location", out folder);
        file.UnlockFile(0, "Checked In By Configurator", 0, null);
        file.ChangeState("Check ENG Design", folder.ID, "Created By Configurator", 0 , 0);
        file.ChangeState("Final Review", folder.ID, "Created By Configurator", 0, 0);
        file.ChangeState("Roll to Standard", folder.ID, "Created By Configurator", 0, 0);

        MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text + " Drawing and Assembly Checked-In");
    }
```